# Imprimir via Navegador em Impressora não fiscal

Tags: javascript, html, css, aplicação-web, impressora

estou com um problema para imprimir via web em algumas impressoras não fiscais, por exemplo bematech.

Estou utilizando html puro, já adicionei várias opções de css e nada funciona. Na Epson eu consigo imprimir normal, tudo certo, quando coloco uma Bematech por exemplo, o conteúdo sai na mesma linha, não respeita nenhuma tag html. Pesquisando vi alguns comentários falando sobre impressoras que não reconhecem textos de navegadores.

O engraçado que no Microsoft Edge foi o único navegador que conseguiu imprimir corretamente.

Alguém teria uma solução para isso?

Comment: Já tentou imprimir em PDF, faz seu relatório em PDF, não?

Comment: Não tentei, será que funciona nessas impressoras??!

Comment: Faz o teste de forma mais simples, abre um pdf no navegado e pede pra imprimir, então tu vai saber se ele mantem as configurações (de preferencia gera o pdf do teu relatório que hoje é em html, depois abre ele no navegador e manda bala)